# Не обновляется результат выполнения формулы гугл таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Делаю таблицу для удобной торговли на рынке. Чтобы получать корректную информацию о цене акций подтягиваю данные с сайта investing при помощи функции IMPORTXML(). Ниже формула для отображения значения цены в долларах. Перепробовал кучу методов: искал скрипты, пытался написать самостоятельно.

```
=ЕСЛИ(X2="USD";ЗНАЧЕН(ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЗАМЕНИТЬ(IMPORTXML(A2;"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']");НАЙТИ(".";IMPORTXML(A2;"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']"));1;"");IMPORTXML(A2;"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']")));ЗНАЧЕН(ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЗАМЕНИТЬ(IMPORTXML(A2;"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']");НАЙТИ(".";IMPORTXML(A2;"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']"));1;"");IMPORTXML(A2;"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']")))/ЗНАЧЕН(ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЗАМЕНИТЬ(IMPORTXML(GetDollarToCurrLink(X2);"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']");НАЙТИ(".";IMPORTXML(GetDollarToCurrLink(X2);"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']");0);1;"");IMPORTXML(GetDollarToCurrLink(X2);"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот так можно вытащить цену акций Амазон:

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/equities/amazon-com-inc";"//div[@class='top bold inlineblock']/span[@id='last_last']");",";"");".";",")
```

Формула убирает "," в разделении разрядов и меняет "." на "," для отображения десятичной части числа.

Comment: Да нет, цену то я получил, просто IMPORTXML() по умолчанию обновляется очень редко. Хотелось бы чтобы на данные можно было опираться, а то там получаются данные 4х-часовой давности.